# Apache Netbeans IDE not responding

Tags: netbeans

I have installed Apache Netbean 16 and doesnt respong as soon as its launches,
I have tried other versions of the same thing.

So am probably doing something wrong with installation

My system is
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2601 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
RAM: 32GB
C-drive 2GB free of 99GB
D- drive 170GB free of 900GB

the apache is installed on the D drive

Comment: Look in the directory where you installed NetBeans. Typically the root directory is called `NetBeans-16`. In there you can see if there is a subdirectory at `NetBeans-16\netbeans\nb\var\log`. The `messages.log` file in that directory may contain relevant error information. If so, you can [edit] your question to include the details.

Comment: What [version of Java](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb16/#_deployment_platforms) are you attempting to use? Please also research [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans+does+not+start+launch+site:stackoverflow.com) for more suggestions. Share your findings.